# Using data-status to get id of element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am attempting to use html's `data-status` to get the id for each looped element I have. I currently am doing this to get the `$status` for each looped record and that works fine, however it does not for the `id` section of this.

I am using a click function for when they click on the status div (I am doing it this way because it will be a way for the user to mark something complete), but I want the click to recognize the entire parent div to enable getting the id for the record.

What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $status = $row['status'];
            $html = "";
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'" data-status="'.$row['id'].'">';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-status" data-status="'.$status.'">'.$status_img. '</div>';
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".goal-post-status", function (event) {
     var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
     var goal_id = $(this).attr("data-status");
     if (status == 0) {
         status = 1;
     }
     else if (status == 1){
         status = 0;
     }
     alert(status);
     alert(goal_id);
```

Comment: it appears from the code posted that you have a mismatch of closing `</div>` tags or is there more that you didn't post?

Comment: Yep you are not closing a div..  For the ID issue: you are listening the click event of the class `.goal-post-status` and you have the data id on the div with `.goal-box` class... You need to fix that too

Comment: @RamRaider I took out all of the unnecessary code. Everything works, just the id is not correct. It gives the value of 0 for an record clicked.

Comment: perhaps `var status = $( this.parentNode ).attr( 'data-status' );`

Comment: The var status works fine. This is the issue: `var goal_id = $(this).attr("data-status");` I am not getting the correct value for that, which needs to be the comment id.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Since I was 'clicking' on the child element, I had to the use `parents()` element to get the whole div - `goal-box`'s `attr` of the id I was requiring.

`var goal_id = $(this).parents('.goal-box').attr("data-status");`